DropdownMenu Input Formatting in Flutter
DropdownMenu<Area>(
                              controller: firstController,
                              width: SizeConfig.containerWidth340,
                              textStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                                fontSize: SizeConfig.fontSize18,
                              ),
                              label: Text(
                                '1 নির্বাচন করুন',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                                  fontSize: firstArea == null
                                      ? SizeConfig.fontSize22
                                      : SizeConfig.fontSize18,
                                ),
                              ),
                              requestFocusOnTap: true,
                              enableFilter: true,
                              menuStyle: AppColors.menuStyle,
                              onSelected: (First? first) {
                                if (firstController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    firstArea = first;
                                    secondThana = null;
                                    secondController.clear();
                                  });
                                }
                              },
                              dropdownMenuEntries: areas
                                  .map<DropdownMenuEntry<First>>((First first) {
                                return DropdownMenuEntry<First>(
                                  value: first,
                                  label: first.name,
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                            )

DropdownMenu<Thana>(
                            controller: secondController,
                            width: SizeConfig.containerWidth340,
                            textStyle: TextStyle(
                              color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                              fontSize: SizeConfig.fontSize18,
                            ),
                            label: Text(
                              '2 নির্বাচন করুন',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.primaryTextColor,
                                fontSize: selectedThana == null
                                    ? SizeConfig.fontSize22
                                    : SizeConfig.fontSize18,
                              ),
                            ),
                            requestFocusOnTap: true,
                            enableFilter: true,
                            enabled:firstArea != null,
                            initialSelection: selectedThana,
                            menuStyle: AppColors.menuStyle,
                            onSelected: (Second? second) {
                              setState(() {
                                secondArea = second;
                              });
                            },
                            dropdownMenuEntries: (firstArea != null &&
                                    firstArea!.areas.isNotEmpty)
                                ? (firstArea!.areas
                                      ..sort(
                                          (a, b) => a.second.compareTo(b.second)))
                                    .map<DropdownMenuEntry<Second>>(
                                        (Second second) {
                                    return DropdownMenuEntry<Second>(
                                      value: second,
                                      label: second.name,
                                    );
                                  }).toList()
                                : [],
                          )


When my first dropdown is open, clicking anywhere outside doesn't reset the labels
If keyboard is checked in filter search, the keyboard is not hiding
secondController will work if firstController.text.isNotEmpty is empty then an error message will popup

DropdownMenu-class i am trying to work by following this method
If anyone can solve the problem it would be helpful.

Can you provide proper minimal snippet will reproduce the same error? 2.try bottomPadding: MediaQuery.viewInsetsOf(context).bottom. 3> You may set to the null. you can checkout multiLevel dropdown button Concept

thanks for replay... i already do that for this DropdownMenu but is is control keyboard?

Sorry, I am not clear about your query. Perhaps you can one specific question with a minimal-issue-reproducible code example
